# Why is my MongoDB aggregation pipeline turning a null to a 0

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running an aggregation pipeline from one collection into an aggregated collection. I have a calculation in the groupby as follows:

```
'$field': { '$sum': {'$multiply': ['$field1', '$field2'] }}
```

In some cases, $field1 is a null, but field2 is an integer e.g. 57. I'd expect this calculation to return null, however 0 is returned. Note: when I experience this issue, $field1 is never not null in the collection I am aggregating due to the match clause I am using.

Please can someone explain the reason for this and what I could do to ensure a null is output?

Edit:
Field 1 and field 2 can hold real values e.g. 56 and 67 in most cases, but sometimes all of the documents returned in the match clause will contain null values for field 1 (never both field 1 and field 2)

Comment: "$field1 is never not null" is not very clear.. does it mean it's always null? but still I don't understand. Could you please edit?

Comment: What do you want to do if both fields are equal to `0`?

Comment: Added edit. If both fields are 0, then the output should be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that according to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) `$sum` ignores non-numeric values. If all operands are non-numeric, $sum returns zero. You can implement the same logic using `$add` as shown below. My initial answer assumed that `$multiply` return zero when one of the value is missing, this does not seem to be the case in Mongo 3.2, but please let me know if this still an issue in your version

```js
db.data.aggregate([
    { $project: { summedProduct: { 
        $add:[ 0, { $multiply: [ "$field1", "$field2" ] } ] }
    }}
])
```

Comment: You can use the `$ifNull` operator on `field1`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Understood, however if the multiply creates the field and sets the value to zero, then the expression will not evaluate to null?

Comment: If added an example, that should solve your problem. As the value now exists, MongoDB does create a default value for it.

Comment: Thanks, however this still results in a 0 value in the fields after the multiply and sum operations :\

Comment: According tot he documentation, $sum ignores non-numeric values. If all operands are non-numeric, $sum returns zero...sigh

Comment: It appears `$add` does keep the null, updated my answer. I have removed the `$isNull` as I didn't need it in MongoDb 3.2. Let me know if you need it in  your version.